# How to move a line using a checkbox and autosort

Tags: google-apps-script

So I'm trying to write a script where I can relocate one row to another sheet using a checkbox, but also want to auto sort both sheets all within the same document.

I seem to be able to do one but can't successfully run all.

Answer (score 0):

**Copies Checked Row from Sheet0 to Sheet1.  Deletes the row in sheet1 that was checked and sorts the data in both sheet0 and sheet1**

Almost everytime I make one of these the user will leave a comment saying that they tried it and they get the error cannot run getRange() of undefined .  And this occurs because this function is setup to run on the event object  of an onEdit trigger.  So  paste into the script editor save it and then start checking checkboxes in sheet1.  You may change the sheet names and adjust the sort directions and columns if you wish.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 11 && e.range.rowStart >1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast('Flag1');
    const sh1 = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");//reset the checkbox
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()-1).copyTo(sh1.getRange(sh1.getLastRow() + 1,1));//copies checked row to sh1
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);//deletes checked row
    sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() -1,sh.getLastColumn(); -1).sort({column:1,ascending:true});
    sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow();//sorts data ascending -1,sh1.getLastColumn()).sort({column:1,ascending:true});//Sorts data only ascending
  }
}
```

- [onEdit Evennt Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

#### Sheet0:

[image]

#### Sheet1:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I am getting this error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined...
I have copied and pasted yours, and adjusted where I need to, but not sure where I have gone wrong, FYI I am new to this.

Comment: Read the answer.  It provides an explanation of your problem.